# How do you Build a GUI shell for DOS?

Tags: shell, operating-system

I would like to build a GUI shell for DOS so I can make a shell operating system like windows. I know this may sound stupid, but I'm just a beginner looking for a challenge. I was thinking something along the lines of Dream16OS but a little better looking. Also is it possible to make this in Visual Basic for DOS or Visual Basic 1 or any recent visual Basic? You can download Download from [GeekBasic.webs.com](http://geekbasic.webs.com)

Also, I have started a project similar to this and could really use some guidance, so please check it out and post in the forum. Thanks Link Below http://boss-basicoperatingsystemsimulation.yolasite.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually recommend you harken back to the days of QBASIC (or QuickBASIC) for DOS and implement a GUI in that. Recognize the pain and suffering before the days of drivers and programming against the hardware yourself. Treat yourself to programming in a constrained environment and realize how well-off albeit wasteful we are with resources nowadays.

If BASIC is beneath you, try something like Turbo Pascal or even Turbo C. Ah, the good old days when you had complete control over the machine. :)

Comment: No, QBASIC is a language that I learned when I recently began programming. Do you have any suggestions on how I would go about this? Thanks, Ricky

Comment: +1 Turbo C. These were awesome times (along with display mode 13H)

Comment: Ill try that (although I don't know c yet) but I still have no Idea what direction to head in

Answer (score 0):

You could start here : http://theguiblog.com/

**QBASIC / FreeBASIC DOS GUI projects.**

> New to the Blog? First of all, welcome
>   to the GUI Blog, you'll soon find that
>   it's much more than a blog, containing
>   reviews, downloads, and screenshots of
>   QBASIC / FreeBASIC GUIs as well as
>   discussion forums. Please feel free to
>   ask questions or post about your own
>   QBASIC / FreeBASIC DOS GUI projects.QBASIC / FreeBASIC DOS GUI projects.

Comment: Thanks. Could you offer any advice and help me with my project on http://boss-basicoperatingsystemsimulation.yolasite.com/? Also how would you go about building a GUI. I couldn't find any info about that on the blog. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

[image: N2K-OS]

2nd version of a desktop I'm working with in Qbasic. BEST I've seen so far for a suggestion is look in the gaming libraries. If you're wanting a quick desktop load, etc with a fairly simple library of functions added in cuz of the gaming libraries for qbasic, then it will solve some issues. This is my attempt at a vesa-less Screen 12 640x480. It loads an icon set like NES loads a sprite sheet first, GETs all the icons as variables, then PUTs them up.